# Re-rendering antd Select components in a Form when changing value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, antd

I’m having trouble with disabling an option in antd with Selects in a Form.

I want to have two Select components working off of the same list of options but without being able to choose the same option on both. To do this, I made a function, renderSelectItems, that gets the value chosen in the first dropdown and disables it for the second dropdown. Additionally, the first option should override the second option, so in the onChange of the first dropdown, if the value will equal the second, it will set the value of the second dropdown to undefined.

However, this isn’t happening. I think the problem is that renderSelectItems is not re-rendered upon the selection of the first dropdown.

I’ve set the dropdowns as dependencies of each other as well as set shouldUpdate to true, but neither are hitting the renderSelectItems call to enforce this disabling.

I’ve recreated this in codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-wing-nxpxr?file=/src/App.tsx